# lower_bound() in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, binary-search

From reading from the Internet, I understand that The `lower_bound()` method in C++ is used to return an iterator pointing to the first element in the range [first, last) which has a value not less than value. This means that the function returns the index of the next smallest number just greater than that number.

So, for the given code below I understood that the output is 3. But, as there is repetition of 6. How can I get the index of last 6 using `lower_bound()`. I can implement my own `binary_search()` for that, but I want to know how to do it by `lower_bound()`.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector> 

using namespace std; 

int main () 
{ 
    int array[] = {5,6,7,7,6,5,5,6}; 

    vector<int> v(array,array+8); // 5 6 7 7 6 5 5 6 

    sort (v.begin(), v.end()); // 5 5 5 6 6 6 7 7 

    vector<int>::iterator lower,upper; 
    lower = lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 6); 
    upper = upper_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 6); 

    cout << "lower_bound for 6 at position " << (lower- v.begin()) << '\n'; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: No actually, the last index of the element that is to be searched e.g. in the given code the output I am looking for is 5. As the element to be searched is 6.

Comment: sounds like you want upper_bound which you are already using. perhaps you need a better question which show exactly what output you want

Comment: `auto lower_plus_one = lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(), 6+1);` Then `lower` and `lower_plus_one` is the range of the 6's.

Comment: Does it really need to be in terms of `lower_bound` and not `upper_bound`?

Comment: @aschepler It isn't really a necessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reverse iterators into the vector, but then to fulfill the ordering requirement for `std::lower_bound` you need to inverse the comparison, so you need to use `std::greater` instead of the default `std::less`. This however also means that now you are not really looking for a lower bound, but for an upper bound with respect to that comparison function, so:

```
auto upper = std::upper_bound(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), 6, std::greater{});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use pair of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`. Or one `equal_range` -- that would be more optimal.

Both `upper_bound` and high part of `equal_range` would be *past*  the last "6". The same as *end* is not last, it is *past* the last.

Comment: I still didn't get it.

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sorted, iterating between `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` you get all elements which equal your pivot point:

```
lower = lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 6);
upper = upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 6);

for (auto it = lower; it != upper; it++) {
    assert(6 == *it);
}
```

The question you are asking, i.e. what is the index of the last `6`, doesn't have a corresponding function in the standard library because is ill-defined in the case when the range doesn't contain any `6`. In all other cases since you have a random access container you can get an iterator to the last `6` by removing one from `upper_bound` (`upper - 1` in your code), in the same way you get the last index of an array by removing 1 from length.
However I suggest you avoid relying on the position of the last element equal when you design your algorithm. Also note that if you need both lower and upper bound you can get both at the same time with `equal_range`, which may even perform better because it may be optimised to only traverse the data structure once:

```
std::tie(lower,upper) = equal_range(v.begin(), v.end(), 6);

for (auto it = lower; it != upper; it++) {
    assert(6 == *it);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lower_bound` again, updating the begin and the value:

```
auto lower = std::lower_bound (v.cbegin(), v.cend(), 6); 
auto upper = std::lower_bound (lower, v.cend(), 6 + 1);

std::cout << "Number of values found: " << std::distance(lower, upper) << '\n';
```